# Simple date filtering query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I was trying to do a simple block on rails and Im getting an error and Im pretty sure is something basic but I lost my head now and since there isnt another programmer here I have nobody to share my idea. I have the following block:

```
 @performances.where('creation >= ?', Date.yesterday).find_each do |per|
```

Im getting in better errors:

```
undefined method `row' for nil:NilClass
```

but when I open a simple rails console and do a query:

```
p = Performance.all.where('creation >= ?', Date.today)
```

I do get errors, anybody has an idea of why I cant get records when using greater or equal.

Now the weird thing is that it works perfectly If I use a less than or equal instead of greater, so if I do this:

```
@performances.where('creation <= ?', Date.yesterday).find_each do |per|
```

it works good but of course I dont want those records..

******************EDIT******************************************

I got more info from the erros:

```
Started GET "/performances.xlsx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 17:42:15 -0600
```

Processing by PerformancesController#index as XLSX
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Performance Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "performances".* FROM "performances" WHERE (creation = '2015-08-10')  ORDER BY "performances"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
  Island Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "islands".* FROM "islands" WHERE "islands"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered performances/index.xlsx.axlsx (17.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `row' for nil:NilClass:
  axlsx (2.0.1) lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/worksheet.rb:698:in`range'
  axlsx (2.0.1) lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/worksheet.rb:615:in `[]'

Im using axlsx_rails

Comment: Do you have any records that creation is >= today? Perhaps it is returning and empty set and that is why the two are different

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same but I got
    SELECT "performances".* FROM "performances" WHERE (creation >= '2015-08-11')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Performance id: 17, island_id: 16, capacity_t1: 5000, capacity_t2: 5000

So I got one record I will edit more error information

Answer (score 0):

*******************************ANSWER**************************************

For everybody that has this problem it was obvious.. I was adding some code to an unexisting row in excel... just remove that and will get it done just as the error says